# what is the benefit in using a wrapper for CURL in php vs using it directly?

Tags: php, curl

I can use straight forward

```
`curl $url -H $headers -d $data`
```

Or I can use the [cURL wrapper functionality](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) and some more wrappers like the ones Zend Framework gives.

I find it easy to use the straight forward approach, am I missing a benefit here? I use cURL for getting JSON responses, so no complex parsing is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The API lets you set various [options](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) that might not have command-line equivalents.
- Error handling is cleaner since you get an error code and can ask for an error string. Getting the errors from the command's return code and stderr is messier.

Btw your backtick version should probably use [escapeshellarg](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) on the $url, $headers and $data especially if any of them depend on user input.

Comment: Very likely the PHP extension since it doesn't create a new process and uses the same libcurl underneath. But the difference is nothing compared to how long the network I/O will take. As always,  don't optimize prematurely and benchmark if you really want to.